# How to change UIServer port for Deeplearning4j from 9000 to some other?

Tags: java, vert.x, deeplearning4j, dl4j

Currently I have a preconfigured VPN client that for some own sake uses exactly 9000 and there is no way to reconfigure it. How can I initiate dl4j's UIServer to some other port?

UIServer is based on Eclipse Vert.x. I have been tried to set up `-Dhttp.port=9001` VM variabe, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way, [as documentation says on 10 april 2020](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/tuning-and-training/visualization#visualizing-network-training-with-the-deeplearning-4-j-training-ui), is using `-Dorg.deeplearning4j.ui.port=9001`.

May another (ugly) way is to use a custom UIServer class and change the method `getInstance` to modify which VertexUIServer port will be used.